# How can I create a lineplot for datetime-indexed data without converting the index to another format?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'd like to make a time-series graph. I have a pd.DataFrame that is indexed by datetime. I'd like to graph this datetime data directly instead of converting it to ordered categorical. I don't want to use `sns.tsplot()` because it warns about deprecation.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

numberofmice = {
    "time": ["2012-01-01 12:00:00", "2012-01-02 12:00:00", "2012-01-03 12:00:00", "2012-01-04 12:00:00"],
    'mice': [8, 5, 3, 12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(numberofmice)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df = df.set_index("time")

sns.lineplot(data = df, x = "time", y = "mice")
```

But this gave `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'time'`.

Comment: `sns.lineplot(data = df, x = df.index, y = "mice")` ??

Answer (score 2):

Create `DatetimeIndex` is not necessary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(numberofmice)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

sns.lineplot(data = df, x = "time", y = "mice")
```

Your code working like pointed @anky_91 - instead `time` use `df.index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(numberofmice)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df = df.set_index("time")

sns.lineplot(data = df, x = df.index, y = "mice")
```